# SQL Order By on the basis of Matching

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, sql-order-by

I have this table, where I am searching for records based on name, description, category_name.
What I want the order of records to be:

1. Results that matched with name or part of the name,
2. Then Results that matched with the description as well as category_name,
3. Results that matched with the only category_name,
4. Results that matched with the description

Please see that I am trying to order the records based on their match. Simple order by name with sorting them all according to name.

Sample Data:

**name,description,category_name**

1. abc,xyz_usama, asz
2. usama,this is description,person
3. abc, xyz, usama
4. jhon,this is usama,person usama

now if I searched using keyword usama:
result should be:

2 ( matched with name )

4 ( description + category )

3 ( category )

1 ( description )

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also be helpful.

Comment: *Sample Data* must be provided in CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts textual form, not like tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression`.  Your question is not really clear on what the data looks like, but the idea is:

```
order by (case when name like '%' || :search || '%' 
               then 1
               when category_name like '%' || :search || '%' and
                    description like '%' || :search || '%'
               then 2
               when category_name like '%' || :search || '%'
               then 3
               when description like '%' || :search || '%'
               then 4
               else 5
          end)
```

Comment: I have added the sample data

Comment: Should I replace the 1 and 2 with something?

Comment: @OsamaKhalid . . . No.  Those are the results from the `case` expression that get sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY 
    /* Results that matched with name or part of the name, */
name LIKE 'name_pattern' DESC,
    /* Then Results that matched with the description as well as category_name, */
    /* Results that matched with the only category_name, */
category_name LIKE `category_name_pattern` DESC, 
description LIKE `description_pattern` DESC
    /* Results that matched with the description */
    /* i.e. all another records */
```

If all pattern are the same substring you may use simple

```
ORDER BY LOCATE('pattern', CONCAT(name, category_name, description))
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'name_pattern' here? and others

Comment: @OsamaKhalid In your particular case all of them are `'%usama%'`

Comment: Yes, the keyword will be same for all conditions. I think this would be the right answer. Let me test.

Comment: @OsamaKhalid The variant for the same pattern for all conditions added.

Comment: What would be the condition for category name and description, where we have a match for both?

Comment: @OsamaKhalid I don't understand. Only full rules set (like in the question) may be considered.

Comment: The second one, the results that were matched to both category and description. Plus the keyword Can be part of the name or other attributes

Comment: But I am not able to find solution for the second option

Comment: @OsamaKhalid For complex rules list use the technique provided by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61795355/10138734). To sort sub-groups within the group you may use nested CASEs.